# MySQL database, select case, and getting two values instead of one

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How could I modify this if I want to get to know both a_player1_name and b_player1_name?

Now this returns the first value which will be found. I mean, either a_player1_name or b_player1_name, but not both of them. Both of them are required.

When chart_matches.a_player1_id = user_list.id, then a_player1_name should be user_list.player_name.

And when chart_matches.b_player1_id = user_list.id, then b_player1_name should be user_list.player_name.

Please help, thank you.

```
SELECT case user_list.id
            when chart_matches.a_player1_id
            then user_list.player_name
       end AS a_player1_name

       , case user_list.id
            when chart_matches.b_player1_id
            then user_list.player_name
       end AS b_player1_name

FROM chart_matches
     , all_lists
     , user_list

WHERE chart_matches.chart_id = 106
      AND ((chart_matches.a_team_id = all_lists.id AND chart_matches.a_player1_id = user_list.id)
      OR (chart_matches.b_team_id = all_lists.id AND chart_matches.b_player1_id = user_list.id))
```

Comment: These column names are a bit hard to read. You may find more help with this if you edit your question and simplify the column and table names...

Comment: Now I tried my best :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want to *aggregate* your results (note the MAX() functions in the version below).

Your original would get 2 *records* - one for each player.  So you have to aggregate the records together, and for this MAX() essentially keeps the value from the record where there was a match for *that specific player*.

```
SELECT max(case user_list.id
            when chart_matches.a_player1_id
            then user_list.player_name
            else null
       end) AS a_player1_name

       , max(case user_list.id
            when chart_matches.b_player1_id
            then user_list.player_name
            else null
       end) AS b_player1_name

FROM chart_matches
     , all_lists
     , user_list

WHERE chart_matches.chart_id = 106
      AND chart_matches.a_team_id = all_lists.id
      AND (chart_matches.a_player1_id = user_list.id OR chart_matches.b_player1_id = user_list.id)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not do the job. Maybe my question was wrong. I have edited its WHERE part, so please take a look.

Comment: Still looks like you would return 2 records: one from user_list where id = chart_matches.a_player1_id, and another from user_list where id = chart_matches.b_player1_id.  Can you confirm what your query above actually returns?  If you run it without MAX(), seems like you'd have one record with "a" not-null and "b" null, and a second record with "a" null and "b" not-null.  What do you see?

Comment: It seems to me that a_player1_name is wrong, but b_player1_name is correct.

Comment: Can you include the results you are seeing in your question? We don't want to guess too long at what you're seeing :)

Comment: Anyway, I need more values than only two. I guess that using MAX is not needes here. Without it I will get more values.